# Failed in using Python to call on wget

Tags: python, subprocess, wget

I can use wget in cmd of windows without problem. But it fails to call wget from command in Python.

My code is:

```
import os
os.system('wget http://www.google.com')
```

The error is:
wget is not recognized as an internal or external command

I have also tried subprocess, it fails as well.

```
from subprocess import *
call(['wget', 'http://www.google.com.hk'])
```

The erros is:
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2]

Comment: Is there any reason why you are using wget within system calls? `urllib` can help here.

Comment: What is your `PATH`? Does it contain `wget`? What is your OS?

Comment: @JayanthKoushik Thanks for your reply. My aim is to call any program running in the cmd, such as FLVstreamer (http://www.nongnu.org/flvstreamer/). While I call FLVstreamer from cmd in Python, the same error occurs like calling wget.

Comment: @Tichodroma My path is C:\Windows\System32, where wget locates in.

Comment: os.system('C:/Windows/System32/wget.exe http://www.google.com')

Comment: If you want to be robust, use full paths for commands that you start from other scripts.

Comment: @ChristianRapp Thank you. Full path works. But it is just annoying.

Answer (score 2):

Add wget to your system path variable and then run the code again.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have set C:\Windows\System32 in my system path variable. But it just fails to call wget. My current solution is to put wget.exe in the same folder of the python script, so that wget can be called.

Comment: You might have to logout so changes to PATH variables have effect

Comment: @ChristianRapp Thanks for your reminder. I have restarted my computer. The odd thing is without stating a full path, wget cannot be called, even the system path variable has been set.

Answer (score 0):

Wget will be recognized only if os.getcwd() returns directory where wget exist. If it is different use absolute path to wget.

Comment: Is there a way to call wget without stating an absolute path? I put wget in C:\Windows\System32  and C:\Windows\System32 has already been set in the system path variable.